# Second button on one activity closes android app down

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an app where i need to be able to switch from one activity to the next but also on the first activity there is a temperature converter which uses a button to calculate the answer. this button used to work but since i have changed the oncreate to allow the switching between activities to work it has stopped working and now just closes the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondScreen.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    // This method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
    // "OnClick property" of the button
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
            RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
            if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
                celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
                fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
            }
            else {
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
                fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
                celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // Converts to celsius
    private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
        return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
    }

    // Converts to fahrenheit
    private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
        return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
    }
 }
```

The logcats empty but this is in the other part

```
 [2013-04-22 14:45:24 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8888 for debugger
   [2013-04-22 15:04:58 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the                               device.] device not found
   com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
   at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
   at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
   at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)
   at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:110)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   [2013-04-22 15:07:18 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8888 for debugger

   4-22 15:26:56.392: W/Trace(909): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   04-22 15:26:56.397: W/Trace(909): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
   04-22 15:26:56.417: D/AndroidRuntime(909): Shutting down VM
   04-22 15:26:56.417: W/dalvikvm(909): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught              exception (group=0x40a70930)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
  04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
  04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): ... 11 more
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at com.example.assignment2project.MainActivity.tempConverterClick(MainActivity.java:42)
   04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): ... 14 more
```

Comment: What is that? sorry new to eclipse

Comment: Window->show View->other->Logcat

Comment: when a crash happens it is logged in the logcat. You can post the same here

Comment: Is your second activity declared in your manifest?

Comment: yes i have declared it

Comment: get your button using switch in `oncreate()` and simply implement individual methods...

Comment: Is there an intended difference between `R.id.Button01` and `R.is.button1` (used in case-switch)?

Comment: i have already used oncreate() for the switching of activities and when i try to use it for this a duplication error occurs

Comment: button01 is the button to switch activities and button1 is the calculate for the temperature conversion

Comment: Can I see your xml for `R.id.button1`?

Comment: See my edited answer below, you have a null pointer exception. I believe it is in regards to your `EditText text` you need to instantiate this object somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a conflict, it doesn't appear you are overriding the `onClick` method so I am assuming that you have defined the `onClick` property in xml as `onClick`, instead of the generic click method, let's try the following:

In xml, define the `onClick` as something like what I show below: `tempConverterClick`

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="tempConverterClick"
    android:text="@string/my_button_txt" />
```

---

Now on the Java side, let's first test with `Toast`:

```
public void tempConverterClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Temp Converter click worked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If that works then lets try your initial code in this new click handler:

```
public void tempConverterClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
        if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
            text.setText(String.valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
            celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
            fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            text.setText(String.valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
            fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
            celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

*To avoid future confusion and the confusion of those who try to help, I would highly recommend changing your naming conventions. Create ID's that relate to the action, purpose, etc. Having `R.id.Button01` and `R.id.button1` is VERY confusing*

---

**Edit**

It appears that when you changed your `onCreate` you may have deleted the `EditText` instantiation.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Add this line with the appropriate ID reference
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondScreen.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: when the calculate button is clicked (button1) the following message comes up "unfortunately assignment2project has stopped" and the app closes

Comment: public void tempConverterClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Temp Converter click worked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}      this worked but when we used the original code with the new handler it closed the app

Comment: Do you get this with the code I am showing above? There should be a `LogCat` error with that message, can you show me that?

Comment: level E   TID -1   Text device disconnected

Comment: That looks to be the last line of the error message, there should be many more lines above it. Possibly starting with `NullPointerException` or something similar?

Comment: is there anything i can change around on the code ? as im out of ideas

Comment: I am out of ideas as well, sorry to say. There is not a lot of information to go off of. I would really look into your `LogCat` it may not be working properly if you aren't getting anything from Force Closes, without that it is really difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: heres some more logcat i have now fixed it 04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): at com.example.assignment2project.MainActivity.tempConverterClick(MainActivity.java:42)
04-22 15:26:56.447: E/AndroidRuntime(909): ... 14 more
04-22 15:26:56.487: W/ActivityManager(273): Force finishing activity com.example.assignment2project/.MainActivity
04-22 15:26:56.487: W/WindowManager(273): Failure taking screenshot for (123x205) to layer 21010

Comment: the top two lines are repeated 100's of times 04-22 15:27:00.837: W/Trace(273): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-22 15:27:00.847: W/Trace(273): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-22 15:27:00.907: I/Choreographer(273): Skipped 43 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 15:27:00.987: I/ActivityManager(273): Process com.example.assignment2project (pid 909) has died.
04-22 15:27:00.998: I/WindowState(273): WIN DEATH: Window{4114d100 u0 com.example.assignment2project/com.example.assignment2project.MainActivity}

Comment: Wonderful, lets work through this, would you mind pasting the full `LogCat` in your question at the bottom for readability?

Comment: thanks for your help, trust it to be one line to cause 5 hours of pain

Comment: Yeah, it happens. Once you get used to reading the `LogCat` it gets easier and things like this get solved much faster. When `NullPointerExceptions` occur I always look for where I could be getting null values and I also check all my `View` calls to make sure they're instantiated. 95% of the time those two are the causes. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

define your switch case method in outside oncreate method and call it with your parameter within onclick method of oncreate. Its like
 checkbuttonclick(buttonid);

where your checkbuttonclick(int id). Will contain method definiton of switch case.